# How to disable blurry camera background on iOS apps

Tags: iphone, facetime, zoom

iPhone is doing autoblur when the person is far away from camera. How to stop autoblur? Went into Apple store, but they could not help.

On Zoom, I checked that the blur setting, the background, and any extra settings were all off, but still there was a background blur.

In Facetime, there is also a blur. If I am not in Portrait Mode, and there is a blur of any object in the background, what is causing that and how can I change this?

Comment: This has been asked before, with equally little detail [& subsequently deleted]. If the Apple Store can't figure it out with the phone in their hands, how are we expected to figure it out with zero detail?

Comment: Did you the Apple Store person you talked to confirm that there is a blur which should not be there?

Comment: Also, what have you and the Apple Store person already tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it’s not just how focus works? you know, like if a lens is focused on the foreground, the background will always get some amount of 'bokeh' (how much depends on the lens, aperture, etc)?